# How to convert String to the name of the Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a large number of arrays containing different data. Each has a name that looks this: `rsf_wings, isa_wings, isa_ships, isa_civs` etc.

I have a function that builds a `String arrayName` out of various components passed to it:

```
public static void AddShips(String fac, String type)
{
        String member = null;
        String arrayName = fac+"_"+type;
}
```

Now I need some way to convert this **arrayName** to the actual name of the array. Roughly it should look like this:

```
member = arrayName[(int) (arrayName.length * Math.random())];
```

Comment: It is not possible, by doing it like this, it shows, that your approach is invalid and you should consider refactoring the code to not need that :). But something similar can be done with List of arrays..

Comment: @X-Pippes Please don't make invalid edits. Tags should not be added in title.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Map`? e.g. `member = mapOfArrays.get(arrayName)[...];`

Comment: Why don't you just pass the array, instead of its name?

Comment: The thing is that i was pretty satisfied with simple checks like if ((fac.equals("rsf)) && ((type.equals("civs"))) -> access array with the name of rsf_civs. But i became problematic once the number of combos got too numerous.

Answer (score 4):

No way to do it in Java. Instead use a Map in order to store the different arrays by name.

```
Map<String, int[]> arrayMap ...
int[] myArray = arrayMap.get(arrayName);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways I see now.

First is by simple using an arrays you want :

```
    Map<String, YourObject[]> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But if you already using map, you should consider using lists :

```
    Map<String, List<YourObject>> yourMap2 = new HashMap<>();
```

It allows you to get `List` or an `Array` of `YourObject` based on name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar if you put arrays into map.

```
public class Holder {

    private Map<String, int[]> arrays = new HashMap<String, int[]>();

    public Holder(String... names) {
          for (String name : names) {
               arrays.put(name, new int[1024]);
          }
    }

    public void addShips(String fac, String type)
    {
        String arrayName = fac+"_"+type;
        int[] array = arrays.get(arrayName);
        ...
    }
}
```

I recommend using `List<Integer>`, `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of int[].

```
public class Holder {

    private Map<String, List<Integer>> arrays = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

    public Holder(String... names) {
          for (String name : names) {
               arrays.put(name, new ArrayList<Integer>());
          }
    }

    public void addShips(String fac, String type)
    {
        String arrayName = fac+"_"+type;
        List<Integer> array = arrays.get(arrayName);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a thorough example. Will try to use it.

Comment: Well, i`ve got a problem. I forgot to mention that all my arrays contain String data. This "member = array.get((int)(array.size()*Math.random()));" gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: I`m also forced to use Java 6. Just in case it might be the problem with current suggestion.

Comment: @Okim Changed for Java 6.

Comment: Still getting nulPointerExceptions. Can you please show an example of how to access a member of this array if it is a String? I`m doing something terribly wrong here it seems...

Comment: @Okim Ask another question with the code you run. It's unclear to me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism called reflection ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28programming%29)) that can be used to do what you want. However, in general you don't want to do that as you can usually do it cleaner with a more object oriented approach.