# Problems with calling a member of array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

With the help of the community i managed to get this problem solved: [How to convert String to the name of the Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560463/how-to-convert-string-to-the-name-of-the-array)

But now i get 'nullPointerExceptions'. Here is the code i use:

```
public class IroncladsAdder
{
public static String weaponId = null;
public static String ship = null;
public static String wing = null;

//map code
private static Map<String, List<Integer>> arrays = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
public void Holder(String... names) {
    for (String name : names) {
        arrays.put(name, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}

//adds weapons to fleets and stations
public static void AddWeapons(CargoAPI cargo, String fac, int count, int type) {

    String arrayName = null;

    int quantity = (int) (Math.random()*5f + count/2) + 1;
    if (count == 1) {quantity = 1;}

    if (type == 0) {arrayName = fac+"_mil_weps";}
    else if (type == 1) {arrayName = fac+"_civ_weps";}
    else {arrayName = fac+"_tech_weps";}

    List<Integer> array = arrays.get(arrayName);

    for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++)
    {
        weaponId = valueOf(arrays.get(arrayName).get((int) (Math.random() * arrays.get(arrayName).size())));
        cargo.addWeapons(weaponId, quantity);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the array:

```
//high-tech UIN weapons
private static String [] uin_tech_weps =
        {
                "med-en-uin-partpulse",
                "lrg-en-uin-partacc",
                "med-bal-uin-driver",
                "lrg-bal-uin-terminator",
                "lrg-bal-uin-hvydriver",
                "lrg-bal-uin-shotgundriver",
                "lrg-en-uin-empbeam",
        };
```

Error indicates that something is wrong with this construction:

```
weaponId = valueOf(arrays.get(arrayName).get((int) (Math.random() * arrays.get(arrayName).size())));
```

NOTE: i`m using Intellij IDEA and Java 6. Application most of the time has advices/fixes for some errors and in this case shows that everything is ok.

What i need is to get a String out of the specific array (that is using a code-generated name) and assign it to 'weaponId'.

Comment: where is your exception at?

Comment: It appears that `arrays.get(arrayName)` is null.  Verify/disprove this by explicitly checking that the line before. What does the caller of the `Holder` constructor pass?  You list your `uin_tech_weps`, but not the connection between that and `arrays`.

Comment: Exception is 'java.lang.NullPointerException' and it points at string 64 which is exactly that 'weaponId = ...' part. It does not give any additional specifics.

Answer (score 1):

When your application start the map with the arrays is empty, then when you try to get the array with name X you get back a null value.

First solution: at startup/construction time fill the map with empty arrays/List for all the arrays names.

Second solution: use this method in order to obtain the array.

```
protected List<Integer> getArray(String arrayName) {
  List<Integer> array = map.get(arrayName);
  if (array == null) {
    array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    map.put(arrayName, array);
  }
  return array;
}
```

P.s.
You can change this code:

```
    weaponId = valueOf(arrays.get(arrayName).get((int) (Math.random() * arrays.get(arrayName).size())));
```

into

```
    weaponId = valueOf(array.get((int) (Math.random() * array.size())));
```

Comment: My IDEA tells that Map.get(arrayName) can`t be referenced from a static content and provides no solutions on how to fix or walk around that.

Comment: And under 'fill the map' you mean manually put arrayName? Like this: 'Map.put('uin_tech_weps', array)'?

Comment: Make the getArray array static if you want to access it from other static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now there is a different error - 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0'

Made the code look like this:

```
private static Map <String, List<Integer>> arrays = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

public static List<Integer> getArray(String arrayName) {
    List<Integer> array = arrays.get(arrayName);
    if (array == null) {
        array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrays.put("rsf_civ_weps", array);
        arrays.put("rsf_mil_weps", array);
        arrays.put("rsf_tech_weps", array);
        arrays.put("isa_civ_weps", array);
        arrays.put("isa_mil_weps", array);
        arrays.put("isa_tech_weps", array);
        arrays.put("uin_mil_weps", array);
        arrays.put("uin_tech_weps", array);
        arrays.put("uin_civ_weps", array);
        arrays.put("xle_civ_weps", array);
        arrays.put("xle_mil_weps", array);
        arrays.put("xle_tech_weps", array);
    }
    return array;
}
```

This is how i now call the array and weaponId:

```
List<Integer> array = arrays.get(arrayName);

for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++)
    {
        weaponId = valueOf(array.get((int) (Math.random() * array.size())));
        cargo.addWeapons(weaponId, quantity);
    }
```

What`s wrong?